# Swift ValueTransformer old "good" code now complains with contemporary swift

Tags: swift

I have an old simple ValueTransformer.  Written just following the conventional pattern to support a GUI interface to edit a specific encoded file format.  I recently has cause to regenerate with current compiler and it is  complaining bitterly about converting Bool.self to AnyClass.  Yeah, OK, I understand that Bool is no longer a Class (if it ever was) it is a frozen Struct.  So the question is that of, is there a Swift way of continuing to use this ValueTransformer for a struct rather than a class?

I can see an ugly solution of wrapping a Bool in a Class and using that but is poor design at best, but if needs must....

Am I missing something obvious in the ever changing world ?

The complaint from the the compiler is on the single line in transformedValueClass

```
    return Bool.self as! AnyClass
Cast from 'Bool.Type' to unrelated type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type') always fails
```

```
class StringToBoolTransformer : ValueTransformer
{
  var boolValue : Bool?
  override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
    if let stringRep = value as? String
    {
      if stringRep.count == 1 {
        boolValue = (stringRep == "1" ? true :(stringRep == "0" ? false: nil))
      }
    }
    return boolValue
  }
  
  override func reverseTransformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
    var boolAsString : String?
    if let boolValue = value as? Bool {
       boolAsString = boolValue ? "1" : "0"
    }
    return boolAsString
  }
  
  override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass
  {
    return Bool.self as! AnyClass
  }

  override class func allowsReverseTransformation() -> Bool {
    return true
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Try to use ```return CFBoolean.self``` in ```transformedValueClass```

Comment: Evidently your `transformedValueClass` method has never been called :D

Answer (score 0):

`(NS)ValueTransformer` relies on Objective-C and the corresponding class of `Bool` is `NSNumber`.

I made the code a bit more *contemporary*

```
class StringToBoolTransformer : ValueTransformer
{
  
  override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
      guard let stringRep = value as? String, 
          stringRep.count == 1,
          ["0","1"].contains(stringRep) else { return nil } 
     let boolValue = stringRep == "1"
     return NSNumber(booleanLiteral: boolValue)
  }
  
  override func reverseTransformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
      guard let number = value as? NSNumber else { return nil }
      return number.boolValue ? "1" : "0"
  }
  
  override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass
  {
      return NSNumber.self
  }

  override class func allowsReverseTransformation() -> Bool {
      return true
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it gives some insights and enables going back into the rest of the code  and bringing  up to contemporary standards 8-)

Answer (score 0):

In Swift `Bool` is a `struct`, NOT a class. So you can never cast it to `AnyClass`.

What you can try as a workaround is use `NSNumber` class as a storage for bool via [NSNumber.init(value: Bool)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumber/1415728-init) and then return `NSNumber.self` from your implementation.